# Difference between Traits?

Tags: scala

Is there any difference between these two `trait`'s?

```
scala> trait Bar[A <: Foo] {
     |    def bippy(x: A): A
     | }
defined trait Bar
```

and

```
scala> trait BarTwo {
     |   type A <: Foo
     |
     |   def bippy(x: A): A
     | }
defined trait BarTwo
```

**EDIT**:

The difference in their names is not a meaningful difference per my question. I'm looking for any difference between these two `trait` constructs.

Comment: Don't think there is based on Martin Odersky's Scala Days talk: https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/scala-where-came-from-where-its-going Start from `0:48:44` or the `More Simplifications` chapter. There Martin shows that in the future your first example will purely be syntactical sugar and it will be translated to your second example.

Comment: @AkosKrivachy "Someday maybe they won't be different" is different from "they're not different".

Comment: @TravisBrown Yeah, my wording may not have been perfect, and that's why I didn't post it as an answer, just as a bit of extra information. In the meantime I ran both samples using `scala -print` and they produce the same generated code, not sure if that's an indication of anything.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. There are a lot of differences between the traits, for example the names. In which way would determine type equality here? After all, there is no `equals` on types.

Answer (score 1):

In most practical cases, there is no difference, and as @AkosKrivachy commented, they are scheduled to be made completely equivalent. Nevertheless, while [the official documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/abstract-types.html) states that

> it is often possible to turn abstract type members into type parameters of classes and vice versa.

It also states at the end that

> Furthermore, there are cases where it is not possible to replace abstract types with type parameters.

Sadly, I could not find any description of what those cases are :-(

I'm posting this as an answer in case given that a better answer might not be forthcoming and you might want to close this, but let's hope.